# Using ACTION_DIAL and backstack

Tags: android, android-intent

When using the Intent.ACTION_DIAL and getting the dialer to open with the number works fine. Lets say I don't want to make the call and try and go back to the app. I have to press the back button 3 times as it navigate through the address book like I was dialing a number. Is there a way so that from the dialer with one back press I will be back on my app?

Comment: Did you find any solution, I have same issue.

Comment: Some solution for this?